# WPF XAML Привязка к корневому свойству внутри шаблона

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, xaml, binding

Не знаю даже как заголовок верно описать.

Имеется XAML:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding AnimeLists}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding URStatusRus}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedView}"><!-- нужное свойство SelectedView находится в корне VM класса, а XAML ищет внутри свойства AnimeLists[i] -->
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Название" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Эпизоды"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Progress}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Оценка"   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Score}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Тип"      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Kind}" />
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

AnimeLists это коллекция из пяти объектов (по одной на вкладку).
У объекта 2 свойства. Одно для заголовка вкладки, другое - список.
Список передаётся ListView, который отображает его в соответствии с шаблоном.

Не забываем, что вкладок 5, а значит и ListView тоже 5.

Теперь я хочу привязать SelectedItem к свойству в VM. 
Если добавлю свойство в класс AnimeLists, то свойств SelectedView (так я назвал свойство в VM) будет 5. И для его связки с другим контролом в другой части интерфейса мне надо знать индекс AnimeLists (то есть индекс активной вкладки).

Поэтому я решил попробовать разместить моё свойство SelectedView в корне класса, чтобы оно получало последний выделенный элемент независимо от открытой вкладки, но дилемма в том, что код не видит поля и свойства "выше" свойства AnimeLists[i].

В связи с чем вопрос, можно ли внутри шаблона как то привязать SelectItem к свойству выше по иерархии, чем AnimeLists[i]. (i - это индекс активной вкладки).

Или может есть ещё какое-то изящное решение, чтобы свойство связанное с выделенным элементом у меня было одно?

Comment: дайте имя Window или UserControl - что у вас там является корневым? И тогда можно привязаться через это имя, вот например для кнопки: `<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.AddSynonymAsNewWordCommand, ElementName=Root}"`, где `Root` это имя данное для UserControl, в которой размещена `ItemsControl`

Comment: @Bulson DataContext у меня задаётся динамически в App.xaml.cs. Класс, который даётся в DataContext окна - MainVM. `var mainWindow = new MainWindow() { DataContext = mainVM }; mainWindow.Show();` как-то так у меня запускается главное окно из App.xaml.cs

Comment: И это прекрасно:) В `mainVM` создайте свойство `SelectedAnime` и тогда вы сможете привязать так:  `DataContext.SelectedAnime, ElementName=Root`

Comment: @Bulson именно Root?

Comment: `Root` это имя данное в XAML для окна `x:Name="Root"` можете назвать как сами хотите.

Comment: Ошибка в окне Output есть? Вы не забыли в свойстве вызывать событие `PropertyChanged`?

Comment: @Bulson вроде заработало.. а что можно сделать с тем, что при переключении вкладки, значение становится null. Можно сделать так, чтобы при смене вкладки сохранялся последний выделенный с прошлой вкладки?

Comment: Добавьте еще одно свойство или приватное поле и сохраняйте туда значение, чтоб сохранить на время переключения вкладки.

Comment: @Bulson добавил условие на не null в сеттер свойства) спасибо за помощь)